# broken view in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

I'm not sure how I describe this problem but in sculp mode my mesh seems like this if I choose backface culling view getting better , but problem continue in some areas, why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a problem with the normals. In Edit mode, select All then Shift - N and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: thanks but nothing changed .  :(

Comment: Did you Voxel remesh your model before you took this? Or perhaps accidentally push `Ctrl+R` (the shortcut to do that)? It looks like how it looks when you try to remesh a model with bad topology/ non-manifold geo.

Comment: yes I made remesh for descent vertices